# Is there a script for generating a migration SQL (postgres) file?

Tags: php, sql, perl, postgresql

On a project I work I have sometimes have to deal with changes on the table structure, like adding fields. Is there a script that can I use for generate a migration SQL file with only the changes?

PHP, bash or Perl would be nice. The database is postgresql.

Comment: What would the input to the script be? Do you have a schema file somewhere? Would it have to compare two schema files?

Comment: Yes I have a schema file more a create script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) there is this module which appears to fit the bill:  [DBIx::Migration::Directories](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Migration-Directories/).

Comment: Interesting. But for what I can tell by the list of packages, `postgresql` may not be supported.

Comment: Under Features section it says "Works with Postgres, MySQL, and SQLite2". The list of packages you're referring to is to "handle quirks" in MySQL and SQLite2 ;-)

Comment: draegtun. Good to know. It just didn't occur to me that there's a single SQL that has no quirks to handle ;-) But then if it was a reference platform... +1 then ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I only know this - [Another PostgreSQL Diff Tool](https://github.com/fordfrog/apgdiff) (it's java, though), but personally I don't trust computers that much and prefer hand-crafted update scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Now similar question with answers in DBA exists:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73846/postgresql-schema-diff-patch-tool

In particular it's offered the next variants:

- [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) migration tool where [comparison](https://flywaydb.org/#features) with other tools is presented
- difference tool in [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip//) IDE
- [diff tool](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html) of liquibase